# SQL Server crashes when trying to backup certificate

Tags: sql-server, openssl, redhat

I am trying to create backup certificate from primary to create certificates on secondary nodes for an availability group. Using the following:

```
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password123';
    CREATE CERTIFICATE dbm_certificate WITH SUBJECT = 'dbm';
    
    BACKUP CERTIFICATE dbm_certificate
       TO FILE = 'dbm_certificate.cer'
       WITH PRIVATE KEY (
               FILE = 'dbm_certificate.pvk',
               ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '123password'
           );
```

The master key and certificate creation are successful but the `BACKUP CERTIFICATE` returns:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
```

This seems to be caused by a core dump by sql giving the following log:

```
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Tue Jan 26 12:25:05 2021
The following diagnostic information is available:

         Reason: 0x00000001
         Signal: SIGABRT - Aborted (6)
          Stack:
                 IP               Function
                 ---------------- --------------------------------------
                 0000559b81252023 malloc_usable_size+0x9e103
                 0000559b81251afe malloc_usable_size+0x9dbde
                 0000559b8125111a malloc_usable_size+0x9d1fa
                 00007fbabc90d400 __restore_rt+0x0
                 00007fbabc90d387 gsignal+0x37
                 00007fbabc90ea78 abort+0x148
                 00007fbabb5ecc8f OpenSSLDie+0x1f
                 00007fbabb6aadcc bad_do_cipher+0x1c
                 00007fbabb6aafba EVP_EncryptUpdate+0xda
                 0000559b8120c8ce malloc_usable_size+0x589ae
                 0000559b8120c4c2 malloc_usable_size+0x585a2
                 0000559b811d60d5 malloc_usable_size+0x221b5
                 0000559b811d5d99 malloc_usable_size+0x21e79
        Process: 11391 - sqlservr
         Thread: 11513 (application thread 0x1c4)
    Instance Id: 2b6201eb-eeba-4f82-8007-7e3ef630be1a
       Crash Id: 98fa6ae2-ac80-4454-839a-06ffba21260a
    Build stamp: 86f25b9af3192b748396bd75b5bf3eceb3e2e62a8c2271521d281f5a53463d38
   Distribution: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
     Processors: 4
   Total Memory: 8370020352 bytes
      Timestamp: Tue Jan 26 12:25:05 2021
```

Removing the `WITH PRIVATE KEY` allows the command to succeed creating dbm_certificate in the data folder.  This lead me to believe the issue was with OPENSSL and the encryption of private key. I have installed MSSQL 2019 on Red Hat 7.9 with OPENSSL 1.0.2k.  I have created symlinks to OPENSSL in /opt/mssql/lib as well as adding :

```
[Service]
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mssql/lib"
```

to the mssql-server service.

Comment: A crash is generally an issue that only MS can resolve. The first thing they will ask is what version, edition, and patch level you are using for both your sql server and your OS. If you look in the requirements, rhel 7.9 is not listed as a [supported platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Interesting that 7.9 is explicitly missed, as 7.2-7.8 are as is 8.0-8.3. perhaps there are known issues with 7.9, and this *might * be one of them.

Comment: The doc that Smor linked is where I went through setup instructions. I just took it that the doc has a published date of JUN20 where as 7.9 was released in SEP20 so that is why it's not included.I can try 8.3, I opted to use 7.9 over RH8 because SQL Server needs Python 2.7 and OpenSSL 1.0 which are default in 7 but not in 8

Comment: I started fresh and used Red Hat 8.3 and everything worked fine. @SMor can you post 7.9 as possible incompatible as an answer so I can accept it as my solution?